# Scan specific sub-folder of every folder in powershell

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I have this script which is working fine

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\folder_to_scan\"
$watcher.Filter = "*.nrrd"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = 
{ 
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    Write-Host "The file '$path' was $changeType at '$(Get-Date)'" -fore green             
}   
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 3600}
```

But in my `C:\folder_to_scan\` I have a lot of sub-directories like `00123`, `00245`, `56002` ... And inside each of them I have `\THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN`

So I tried this `$watcher.Path = "C:\folder_to_scan\*\THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN\"` and `$watcher.Path = "C:\folder_to_scan\[0-9]*\THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN\"`

But this is not working. Is it possible to use wildcard in this situation?

---

If not, how to use multi path with `FileSystemWatcher`?
Because I figured out that we can use this

```
Resolve-Path "C:\folder_to_scan\*\THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN\" | Select -ExpandProperty Path
```

Comment: i'm sorry but how is this working fine? while ($true) {sleep 3600}
This will just keep your script waiting for eternity because $true will always be true. What you'd want to do is a do{}while()

So what you wanna do is, scan each subdirectory that has a name like "THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN" ?

What i would do is use Get-childitem and search for all path's that has that name in the foldername.When you get those, then you start focusing on monitoring them.

Comment: The `sleep 3600` is to only monitor this once per hour. I shorted this code because it was more complex and I do a lot of more things in `action`. Anyway, how to give a list of path to `FileSystemWatcher`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `FileSystemWatcher` so I am assuming you just need to feed in the folder paths to `$watcher.Path`

I'm also assuming your code works already.

try using `Get-ChildItem` and use a for loop:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
Get-ChildItem "C:\folder_to_scan\" -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.EndsWith("THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN")}| %{ 
    $watcher.Path = $_.FullName #change this
    $watcher.Filter = "*.nrrd"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
}
    $action = 
    { 
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        Write-Host "The file '$path' was $changeType at '$(Get-Date)'" -fore green             
    }   
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 3600}
```

Comment: I can use `Get-ChildItem` or `Resolve-Path` to retrieve a list of path like explained in my post. But how to give multiple arguments to `FileSystemWatcher`? That's where I'm stuck. Do I have to use multi instance of `FileSystemWatcher` instead? This seems not elegant at all

Comment: That's nearly perfect. The only problem is when a folder is created after the launch of the powershell script. It will not work...I tried to put the `while ($true) {sleep 3600} ` after the final `}` but it is not working

Comment: Yes, I just tried again to be sure and yes it was working before

Comment: do you get any error messages? where does it stop working?

Comment: With your code, this is working only for the first path of the loop because the script is stuck in the loop because of the `while` (I think). With the `while` outside, I dont have any error but it is working for each folder already existing (not the new ones) but the `Write-Host` is triggered multiple time (related to number of given path I think)

Comment: i don't see a new file getting created in your script.. I was assuming write host needed to be triggered every time from your post, if it doesn't you can take it out the for loop. Its hard to tell exactly what needs to be done without more code. Anything you need to loop with the folder name put it inside the loop... everything else goes outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to clarify what i was talking about earlier. You are only repeating your wait-function. To show you what i mean :

```
    echo "This would be your code running."
    while ($true) {sleep -second 3}
```

This would print the sentence once and then keep waiting for eternity for 3 seconds each time $true is true.

What you need to do is :

```
do{
   echo "This would be your code running."
   sleep -seconds 3
} while($true)
```

This will print the sentence every 3 seconds.
Or in your case, run your watcher every 3 seconds.

Comment: You are right but watchers does not work like that.
You can check this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a perfect solution so I did this

```
if ( $path -like '*\THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN\*' ) 
{ Write-Host "File created in \THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN" -fore green }
else
{ Write-Host "File created NOT in \THE_DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN" -fore red }
```